# releasing surfaceview

Tags: android, surfaceview, viewgroup

I have a custom `ViewGroup` that contains about 10 `SurfaceView`'s. When you push a button a xml file gets parsed and a skin gets generated which contains 10 more surface views. These then get added to the view group, the view group gets invalidated, and the previous 10 surfaceviews get removed by `viewgroup.removeView`. This is to avoid flickering. It all works great but after doing it maybe 8 times I begin to run out of memory and `lockCanvas` returns null on the new surfaceviews. Is `removeView`, and setting all references to the surface view to null all you need to release a surface? Here is what the code looks like that removes the view:

```
if (viewsToRemove.isEmpty() == false) {

    this.post( new Runnable() 
    {  
        public void run() { 
            if (viewsToRemove.isEmpty() == false) {
                for (IView v : viewsToRemove) {
                    SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView)v;
                    removeView(sv);
                    v.cleanup();
                }
                viewsToRemove.clear();
                System.gc();
                invalidate();
            }
        } 
    }); 
}
```

This block of code gets run  in `onDraw` after the new `SurfaceView`'s get painted (to avoid flickering). I've tried experimenting with garbage collection and also with manually calling the `SurfaceView`'s finalize method which is what the `v.cleanup` call does but still runs out of memory after a while. It seems to work on Android 4.0 but not on  <= 2.3.x.

Here are the errors adb shows:

```
09-25 14:51:01.419: E/Surface(4131): Surface (identity=17237) requestBuffer(1, 0, 0, 1, 00000203) returned a buffer with a null handle
09-25 14:51:01.419: E/Surface(4131): getBufferLocked(1, 0, 0, 1, 00000203) failed (Out of memory)
09-25 14:51:01.419: E/Adreno200-EGL(4131): egliSwapWindowSurface: unable to dequeue native buffer
09-25 14:51:01.469: E/Surface(4131): Surface (identity=17237) requestBuffer(1, 0, 0, 1, 00000203) returned a buffer with a null handle
09-25 14:51:01.469: E/Surface(4131): getBufferLocked(1, 0, 0, 1, 00000203) failed (Out of memory)
09-25 14:51:01.469: E/Adreno200-EGL(4131): eglLockWindowSurface: unable to dequeue native buffer


09-25 14:51:01.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4131): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 25
09-25 14:51:01.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4131): java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
09-25 14:51:01.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4131):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1080)
09-25 14:51:01.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4131):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1038)
09-25 14:51:01.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4131):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1364)
09-25 14:51:01.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4131):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believed I solved this. I think not all Views were being added to the viewsToRemove ArrayList due to incorrect conditional logic.